# Android ScrollView: Bottom Button not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, scrollview

The problem is I want to make my registration activity scrollable, but whenever I launch the app,I can scroll but I cannot view the button below. I have tried putting alignParentTop = true and it focuses on the first edittext.

Here is my code:

```
 <LinearLayout>

      <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Add CONi icon here -->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editlastname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/lastname"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:text="@string/signup"
            android:textColor="@color/color3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use This XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Add CONi icon here -->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editlastname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="lastName"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="signup"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Mostafa, welcome to stack overflow. Here we are trying to help people. But helping them doesn't mean we are just providing code for just copy-paste. We are also explaining why? and where to change. Please try to explain your answer instead of just providing code. Good luck at SOF and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this common problem is giving the last view/widget a "bottom margin", if the problem persists please add a marginTop value too.
This worked for me , hopefully it works for you too!